# Qwt missing includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qwt

When typing the following line:

```
QwtPointSeriesData* myData = new QwtPointSeriesData;
```

It says to me that identifier is undefined. But I have typed the following includes in which, it was mentioned that it cannot open those opens pource files.

```
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>
#include "qwt_series_data.h"
```

Any ideas how to solve and find out how to get them?

Comment: Why do you use double quotes and angle brackets for headers from the same lib at the same time? One of the common practices is to reference external lib is to (1) reference path to its headers in your compiler include dir and (2) include headers in source files through "<>". This should do the trick for compile stage. Have you done both of these steps?

Comment: @leo Yes I have already did that, but the problem is that, it recognized the two following includes:#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include "qwt_curve.h" but the series data and the plot curve: no

Comment: Do these files exist? If they do are they in the same folder as qwt_plot_curve.h or some other folder. If they are in some other folder is that in Your additional Include directories?

Comment: @drescherjm, But, still, a new problem : Cannot open include file: 'qmemarray.h': No such file or directory –

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question :
It seems that I was having an very old version of QWT!

Comment: I use version qwt 6.0.x with visual studio (2008 through 2012). However I always compile it myself and use it with CMake for project generation.

Comment: @Drescherjim do you have any idea how to use Cmake for project generation on WIndows ?

Comment: Yes of course, I use CMake on windows with Visual Studio (versions 2003 to 2012 x32 and x64) for the last 5 or so years for all of my projects at work. With that said its not something I can teach you in a few comments.. There is no quick secret that makes everything work. You need to learn CMake which will take time.